# c++ derived class with private access specifier

Tags: c++, access-specifier

I have a derived class (class B) from a base class (class A). Class A has a protected virtual function foo() which I want to override and use it as private in derived class.

```
Class A{
  protected:
   virtual void foo() = 0;
}
```

I am wondering whether the following

```
Class B: public Class A
  private:
    virtual void foo();
```

and

```
Class B: private Class A
  private:
    virtual void foo();
```

are the same.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same. In the first example, `B` *is-an*-`A`, in the second it isn't. So in the first case you can have code such as

```
void foo(const A& a);
```

which accepts `A` and `B` as arguments. With private inheritance, you could not do that. For example,

```
A a;
B b;
foo(a); // OK with private and public inheritance
foo(b); // OK only with public inheritance, i.e. B is an A.
```

Comment: I think in the second case `B` is-an-`A` too, although you can not address `B`'s object by `A`'s reference (or pointer).

Comment: @MM. I would say it *has-an-A*, but I realise maybe there is no consensus about this.

Comment: @juanchopanza Can you give an example and do you know any place which explains this more detailed? I did not get it completely.

Comment: @AvbAvb I added a little example that illustrates what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

No, your two cases are not the same.

In the second case `class B` can't be casted to `class A`, because a private base class is hidden. in this aspect would get the same behavior as if `class A` would be a member of `class B`.

Answer (score 0):

No both are not same
In public inheritance class A's foo() will be protected member in class B
In private inheritance class B can only access the public members of the class A so there will not present any foo() of class A in class B.